# Popover not showing in button inside table row

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a table being built via the *map* function of JavaScript (ReactJS).

On the last column, I should be having buttons that are meant to open a popover that will (eventually) hold some information. This cell is being done like this:

```
<td>
    <div>
        <button className="btn btn-primary"
                tabIndex="0"
                role="button"
                data-toggle="popover"
                data-trigger="focus"
                title="Details"
                data-content="Testing, Testing">
               <b>IN PIT</b>
         </button>
    </div>
</td>
```

So far, the said button appears, but no popover whatsoever. I'm not using npm or anything of the sorts since I'm not a front-end-designer myself, and that doesn't seem trivial to setup. I just want something "good enough" for testing purposes.

What am I missing?

Comment: First of all your jsx is invalid, look at your `<button>` tag, you are missing `>`. Does it work now after this small fix?

Comment: I had it since the start, must've been an error copying the code, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your https://pastebin.com/KuRHjWxr. Popovers won't work, you have to implement them other way. 
You initiate 
`$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();` when there are no buttons in DOM.

Call `.popover()` and `.tooltip()` after your buttons are successfully rendered to the DOM.

Comment: After hours of scouring the web, all I had to do was change those 2 lines out of place... You're a life saver, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The names of your attributes imply that you are expecting bootstrap (an external library) to be loaded and attach to the element to provide functionality, is bootstrap included in a script tag on the page? Those attributes don't do anything themselves, they are just tags to attach actions to. Add a [bootstrap cdn](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) tag inside the bottom of the body tag to address.

Comment: You mean the links on the index.html? I think I got them right... 
Anyway, here's the contents of my file at the moment: https://pastebin.com/ekQLjmYM
Thank you!

Comment: This page implies you need some extra dependencies to use popovers, try including them too. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/popovers/

Comment: I updated the dependencies, as it is here: https://pastebin.com/KuRHjWxr
Still nothing. It's been hours, should I give up on popovers in ReactJS?